# MAC M1 ARM Core - Ruby and Gem pg installation issues

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, homebrew, pg

Just wanted to post a question I am facing issues installing `gem install pg -v '0.21.0'` for 2 projects in my system which is an M1 Mac, has anyone faced issues like this

This is the error I am getting

```
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes 
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no 
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no 
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no 
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
> *** extconf.rb failed ***
```

Postgres is installed via Homebrew and libpq is also installed, I tried to point to the libpq when gem pg is being installed and try and fix the problem but that is not working too attaching the mkmf log for more details on the error  and FYI Postgres is installed and I can also connect to it via terminal and other software. I tried a lot of answers from stack to no avail I am pretty new to Ruby and MAC any help will be great

More info but not sure if relevant had issues installing ruby versions 2.5.0 and 2.3.6 but that is now fixed (was showing as broken earlier so purged it and installed again after manually configuring openssl@1.0 to MAC) but when it was broken both pg and bundle install worked fine for one of my project but the Ruby 2.3.6 version failed to install

EDIT 1

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.3.6p384 (2017-12-14 revision 61254) [x86_64-darwin20]
which ruby
/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.6/bin/ruby
rvm list
=* ruby-2.3.6 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.5.0 [ x86_64 ]
which openssl
/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.0/bin/openssl
postgres --version
postgres (PostgreSQL) 14.0
```

EDIT 2

have also had issues with nokogiri not sure if that's the issue

Let me know if you need anymore info any assistance will be greatly appreciated

> MKMF Log

```
find_executable: checking for pg_config... -------------------- yes

--------------------

"gcc -o conftest -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0/x86_64-darwin20 -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wmisleading-indentation -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib -L. -fstack-protector     -lruby.2.5.0  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0/x86_64-darwin20 -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wmisleading-indentation -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib -L. -fstack-protector     -lruby.2.5.0  -Wl,-rpath,/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */

find_header: checking for libpq-fe.h... -------------------- yes

"gcc -E -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0/x86_64-darwin20 -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wmisleading-indentation -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
/* end */

--------------------

find_header: checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... -------------------- yes

"gcc -E -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0/x86_64-darwin20 -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wmisleading-indentation -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <libpq/libpq-fs.h>
/* end */

--------------------

find_header: checking for pg_config_manual.h... -------------------- yes

"gcc -E -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0/x86_64-darwin20 -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wmisleading-indentation -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <pg_config_manual.h>
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0/x86_64-darwin20 -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wmisleading-indentation -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib -L. -fstack-protector -Wl,-rpath,/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib     -lruby.2.5.0 -lpq  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib/libpq.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PQconnectdb", referenced from:
      _t in conftest-f3b0c7.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 8: {
 9:   if (argc > 1000000) {
10:     printf("%p", &t);
11:   }
12: 
13:   return 0;
14: }
15: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))PQconnectdb; return !p; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0/x86_64-darwin20 -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wmisleading-indentation -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib -L. -fstack-protector -Wl,-rpath,/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib     -lruby.2.5.0 -lpq  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c:15:13: error: conflicting types for 'PQconnectdb'
extern void PQconnectdb();
            ^
/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include/libpq-fe.h:285:16: note: previous declaration is here
extern PGconn *PQconnectdb(const char *conninfo);
               ^
conftest.c:16:27: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'conninfo' was not specified
int t(void) { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
              ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include/libpq-fe.h:285:16: note: 'PQconnectdb' declared here
extern PGconn *PQconnectdb(const char *conninfo);
               ^
2 errors generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 8: {
 9:   if (argc > 1000000) {
10:     printf("%p", &t);
11:   }
12: 
13:   return 0;
14: }
15: extern void PQconnectdb();
16: int t(void) { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0/x86_64-darwin20 -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wmisleading-indentation -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib -L. -fstack-protector -Wl,-rpath,/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib     -lruby.2.5.0 -llibpq  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
ld: library not found for -llibpq
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 8: {
 9:   if (argc > 1000000) {
10:     printf("%p", &t);
11:   }
12: 
13:   return 0;
14: }
15: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))PQconnectdb; return !p; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0/x86_64-darwin20 -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wmisleading-indentation -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib -L. -fstack-protector -Wl,-rpath,/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib     -lruby.2.5.0 -llibpq  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c:15:13: error: conflicting types for 'PQconnectdb'
extern void PQconnectdb();
            ^
/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include/libpq-fe.h:285:16: note: previous declaration is here
extern PGconn *PQconnectdb(const char *conninfo);
               ^
conftest.c:16:27: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'conninfo' was not specified
int t(void) { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
              ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include/libpq-fe.h:285:16: note: 'PQconnectdb' declared here
extern PGconn *PQconnectdb(const char *conninfo);
               ^
2 errors generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 8: {
 9:   if (argc > 1000000) {
10:     printf("%p", &t);
11:   }
12: 
13:   return 0;
14: }
15: extern void PQconnectdb();
16: int t(void) { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0/x86_64-darwin20 -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wmisleading-indentation -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib -L. -fstack-protector -Wl,-rpath,/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib     -lruby.2.5.0 -lms/libpq  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
ld: library not found for -lms/libpq
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 8: {
 9:   if (argc > 1000000) {
10:     printf("%p", &t);
11:   }
12: 
13:   return 0;
14: }
15: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))PQconnectdb; return !p; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0/x86_64-darwin20 -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wmisleading-indentation -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/akshayvenugopal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib -L. -fstack-protector -Wl,-rpath,/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib     -lruby.2.5.0 -lms/libpq  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c:15:13: error: conflicting types for 'PQconnectdb'
extern void PQconnectdb();
            ^
/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include/libpq-fe.h:285:16: note: previous declaration is here
extern PGconn *PQconnectdb(const char *conninfo);
               ^
conftest.c:16:27: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'conninfo' was not specified
int t(void) { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
              ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include/libpq-fe.h:285:16: note: 'PQconnectdb' declared here
extern PGconn *PQconnectdb(const char *conninfo);
               ^
2 errors generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 8: {
 9:   if (argc > 1000000) {
10:     printf("%p", &t);
11:   }
12: 
13:   return 0;
14: }
15: extern void PQconnectdb();
16: int t(void) { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------
```

Comment: Your libpq was built without pg support, probably

Comment: I added the flags -- --with-pg-config='PATH' but that did not work too